# How do you understand the relation between the number of parameters and the VC dimension of a hypothesis class?

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

It is often the case that the VC-dimension of a hypothesis class equals (or can be bounded above by) the number of parameters one needs to set in order to define each hypothesis in the class.

For instance, if $H$ is the class of axis aligned rectangles in $R^d$, then $VCdim(H) = 2d$ , which is equal to the number of parameters used to define a rectangle in $R^d$.

How do you understand such a phenomenon?

Answer (score 1):

The intuition that VC-dimension is simply an instance of "parameter counting" is wrong.

Below is a famous counter-example. For any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ define a function $f_{t}$ taking values in
$\{-1, +1\}$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
  f_{t}(x) &=
    \begin{cases}
       +1 & \text{if }\sin(tx) \geq 0,\\
       -1 & \text{if }\sin(tx) < 0.
     \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Consider a concept (or hypothesis) class
$$
  \mathcal{C} = \{ f_{t} : t \in \mathbb{R} \}.
$$

Then for any $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and any sample $x_{1}, \dots, x_{d} \in [-1, 1]$ the concept class $\mathcal{C}$ can achieve any labelling of the given sample. The key idea is that for large values of $t$ the function $\sin(tx)$ oscillates at a very high frequency. Since we are free to choose this frequency, any labeling of the sample $x_{1}, \dots, x_{d}$ is possible to achieve.

Hence, we have constructed a concept class of **infinite VC-dimension** which is parameterized with only **one parameter**.